# How can make parent list data-expanded value to "true" if no Sublist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i change the parent list to expanded `data-expanded="true" if sub list is empty or if there is no sub list?

```
<ul class="treeview">
    <li data-expanded="false" class="panel-handler rparty" data-id="@item.ID">
        <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>@item.PartyName
        <ul>
            @foreach (var sp in rp.Details)
            {
             <li class="panel-handler sParty" data-expanded="false" data-id="@sp.SpartyID"></li>            
            }
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: `$('li.rparty').not(':has(li.sParty').attr('data-expanded' , true);`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef it expand all, i want to expand if no child li

Comment: can you add demo code  ?